# Will I get another chance to punch that reporter?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I was multitasking while doing my first run through the Citadel when I came upon Khalisah al-Jilani.  I fully expected some sort of conflict with her, and caught the first Renegade interrupt.  However, I immediately took my hand off my mouse and started working on my other computer, and didn't make it in time for the second Renegade interrupt.

I'm ashamed to say that a reporter knocked me on my rear.  I'm dying for some revenge (okay, technically she was just getting revenge on me, since I decked her good in both Mass Effect 1 and 2).

Will there be another chance to show her how much of a fan I am?  Or did I blow my chance until Mass Effect 4?

Comment: you missed the opportunity to head butt her, that is worthy of reloading to complete :P

Comment: I got a renegade interrupt and all I did was insult her and ended the interview :/

Comment: @BenBrocka That would have been preferable... I took a swing at her, she dodged my punch, said "not this time" (or words to that effect), popped me one then walked away.

Comment: Yeah I got that my last playthrough, I set my controller down...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not have another opportunity to knock her around in this playthrough, no. If you skip the Renegade interrupt, you may be able to make her a war asset with a Paragon interrupt, during the same conversation.